# How to Get Rid of White Space At Bottom of HTML?

Tags: html, css, css-position, padding

First off, the other searches like this had different styles and I couldn't find one that worked.

I have this large white space at the bottom of my page and I believe it may be because of how all my position relatives possibly stacked on one another because of the negative tops. I barely know what I'm doing.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US" class="has-lab-nav-bottom lab-theme-light">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Portfolio - Nafi Chowdhury</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>


<body class="labs-template-default single single-labs postid-2409 logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support">

<div class="container" style="background-color:red;padding-bottom:-500px;"">

  <div class="wrapper" style="background-color:grey;padding-bottom:-500px;">

<div id="logo" >
<img src="name.png" width=475px  height=225px>
</div>

<div class="intro" >
<table width=100%><tr>
    <td><a href="Home.html"><div id="nav">HOME</div></a></td>
    <td><a href="About Me.html"><div id="nav">ABOUT ME</div></a></td>
    <td><a href="Portfolio.html"><div id="nav">PORTFOLIO</div></a></td>
    <td><a href="Extracurriculars.html"><div id="nav">EXTRACURRICULARS</div></a></td>
    <td><a href="Gallery.html"><div id="nav">GALLERY</div></a></td>
    <td><a href="Contact Me.html"><div id="nav">CONTACT ME</div></a></td>
      </tr></table>

</div><!-- .intro -->

<div class="portfoliothumbnails" id="thumbnail1"><img src="Medicine.png" width=250px height=250px></div>
<div class="portfoliotitles" id="portfoliotitle1"Medical Program</div>
<div class="portfoliotext" id="portfoliotext1">Lorem ipsum stuff about school I don't exactly wanna share blah blah ya yeet I have no clue what to write here</div>
<button class="button" id="button1">Learn More</button>

<div class="portfoliothumbnails" id="thumbnail2"><img src="English.png" width=250px height=250px></div>
<div class="portfoliotitles" id="portfoliotitle2">English Esssays/Documents</div>
<div class="portfoliotext" id="portfoliotext2">A collection of my essays and analysis responses throughout my high school career in Language Arts. </div>
<button class="button" id="button2">Learn More</button>

<div class="portfoliothumbnails" id="thumbnail3"><img src="Trends.png" width=250px height=250px></div>
<div class="portfoliotitles" id="portfoliotitle3">Newspaper Publications</div>
<div class="portfoliotext" id="portfoliotext3">Lorem ipsum stuff about school I don't exactly wanna share blah blah ya yeet I have no clue what to write here</div>
<button class="button" id="button3">Learn More</button>

<div class="portfoliothumbnails" id="thumbnail4"><img src="Art.jpg" width=250px height=250px></div>
<div class="portfoliotitles" id="portfoliotitle4">Creative Work</div>
<div class="portfoliotext" id="portfoliotext4">Work from English and Art such as plays, poems, drawings, photoshop work, and other forms of creative literature. The majority of this section is populated by my work from the creative writing and journalism class, Writing for Publication, I took my freshman year and Digital Arts I from my sophomore year.</div>
 <button class="button" id="button4">Learn More</button>



</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#logo{position:absolute;}
body {
margin-left:25%;
margin-right:25%;
}

#nav{text-decoration:none;
font-size:15px;
font-family:Roboto, sans-serif;
color:black;
padding-top:90%;}

a{text-decoration:none;}

.portfoliothumbnails{position:relative;}

#thumbnail1{left:0%;padding-top:0%;background-color:blue;}
#thumbnail2{left:0%;top:-150px;background-color:green}
#thumbnail3{left:0%;top:-225px;background-color:red}
#thumbnail4{left:0%;top:-325px;padding-bottom:0%;}


.button{  background-color: black; 
   border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family:Roboto, sans-serif;
  position:relative;
  font-weight:bold;}

 .button:hover{opacity:0.7;}

#button1{top:-200px;left:75%;}
#button2{top:-300px;left:75%;}
#button3{top:-400px;left:75%;}
#button4{top:-500px;left:75%;}

.portfoliotitles{position:relative;
color:black;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:Roboto, sans-serif;}

#portfoliotitle1{top:-200px;left:25%;z-index:999;}
#portfoliotitle2{top:-350px;left:25%;z-index:999;}
#portfoliotitle3{top:-400px;left:25%;z-index:999;}
#portfoliotitle4{top:-550px;left:25%;z-index:999;}

 .portfoliotext{position:relative;
color:black;
font-size:16px;
font-family:Roboto, sans-serif;
margin-right:25%;
background-color:red;
}

#portfoliotext1{top:-200px;left:25%;}
#portfoliotext2{top:-350px;left:25%;}
#portfoliotext3{top:-400px;left:25%;}
#portfoliotext4{top:-550px;left:25%;}
```

I had no clue how to position the strips of each of the 4 sections so that they would be responsive when resized so i changed them from relative to absolute and used negative tops so they would not push each other down. I still have no clue how to get rid of the big white space at the bottom as adding margin bottom to html or my wrapper or container or anything of the such does nothing.

Comment: try adding `html,body{margin:0px;padding:0px;}`

Comment: didn't work, but thanks for the reccomendation

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve but for example you could try to add this property to the `html` tag:

`html {height: 100vh}`

that will cut off that additional grey space and let you view 100% of the actual viewport.

Comment: Didn't work it stayed the same and if i added it to the conjoined huge list of tags with html, it stretched everything